# trigger physical 'police' light from my online web app

Tags: php, mysql, light

strange question but just looking for guidance or advice. My web app has the finctionality of assisting operators with timings. my mandate is to turn on a red flashing light (police light) from a mysql php trigger?

Can this be done as I dont think a website can interface with my hardware or is there a web based 'light' available?

alternatively do you get a usb light to communicate with a local mysql database that can talk to the hardware?

Thanks for your time and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are no strange questions. Your question could probably do with tags on the subject of controlling hardware, but I'm not sure what they would be.

Meanwhile this instructable "Arduino Internet Controlled Desk Lamp" might help.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Internet-Controlled-Desk-Lamp/?ALLSTEPS

Answer (score 1):

You could get an Arduino and then use the php-serial class for connecting to it.